# Eclipse kepler minimized on startup and on every reselection of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

Whenever I start Eclipse, it starts with all of the editors minimized, and every time I select a different program (such as the web browser), and then return to Eclipse every editor window gets minimized again.

The picture below shows what I mean by minimized.

[image: eclipse window]

This is very frustrating, and I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Try to make a new fresh workspace. Sometimes it helps with weird Eclipse behavior (namely if you are using workspace created by a different version of Eclipse).

Comment: What version of Java you are using to bootstrap Eclipse?

Comment: Pavel Horal, your solution fixed my problem!
if you will post it as an answer I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

From the screen cap it appears that you've (somehow) gotten the Perspective *stack* minimized. If you just click on the 'restore' button (the top one) on the element in the left trim you're likely going to be OK.

Not sure how you got into this state though, we only minimize the perspective stack when a view that's outside *any* perspective (like 'Welcome') gets maximized...

Comment: the restore button doesn't do anything when I click it. the next button (java) restores everything, but the next time everything gets minimized again.

Comment: Hmmm, if hitting the restore button doesn't do anything the model is quite corrupt. Try to open the 'Welcome' (Help -> Welcome on the main menu) and close it again. Under ordinary conditions this will first collapse and then restore the perspective stack, maybe it'll kick you back into a sane state...

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Appearance -> Maximize Active View or Editor